# Disable saving when closing a file from editor

Tags: save, autosave

When I open a .php file and make changes it will be saved automatically when I close Visual Studio, but this is not what I want the editor to do.

I just want a file to be saved only if I save it myself and not automatically.

Comment: Which Visual Studio? Are you referring to Visual Studio Code?
Anyway this question seems off-topic here on SO, as it's only marginally related to programming.

Comment: I would recommend a version control system for your files! There are free, integrate with IDEs (like Visual Studio) and come in different flavors. Most popular today is https://git-scm.com.

Comment: @ventiseis Visual Studio Code itself ships with GIT SCM integration.